# Siblings vs. Children in the Composition of UIs in QML

Tags: performance, qt, qml, qtquick2

In QML objects are described in an visual hirarchy, where each object has it's (visual) parent (additionally to the 'other parent', which I don't want to talk about here.)

Now I have multiple ways of composing my UI.
Consider:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 700
    height: 700
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: baseRect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 400
        height: 400
        color: 'red'

        Rectangle {
            id: protrudingChild
            width: 200
            height: 200
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.bottom
            color: 'green'
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: containedSibling
        width: 350
        height: 350
        anchors.centerIn: baseRect
        color: 'blue'
    }
}
```

There I have three Rectangles. The `baseRect` is the one the other two are anchored to. Now I have two cases:

1. `protrudingChild` is a child of the `baseRect` but it is not completely contained in it.
2. `containedSibling` is a sibling of the `baseRect` but it is completely contained in it.

This highlites my options: In the extrem I might build the whole file as some sort of "linked list" where no object has siblings, or the other extreme - a flattened hirarchy, in which the tree has a depth of one, as only the root node has children, and the lot is sibling to each other.
The latter gives me the ultimate freedom to anchor to whatever object I want, as I can anchor to all siblings.

However I think that the QML-Enghine uses the hirarchy to build the it's `SceneGraph` and maybe performs other optimizations, and therefore I guess that the composition of the UI has not only implications on the read- and maintainability of the code, but might also affect the performance.

So far my rule of thumb has been: 'If it forms a logical unit and/or object `a` is completely within the bounds of `b` (for most of the time), `a` should be a child of `b`, otherwise a sibling or a farther relation."

But I don't have any facts that back this rule. Can anybody explain the implications on the performance (if there are any) of the composition of my QML-Files?

Comment: When it reaches the renderer, the things that matter: overlap of the polygons and their opaqueness (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html). Run it with the `QSG_VISUALIZE=overdraw` variable. I don't think that there will be a difference between traversing a too deep or too shallow data structure (unless there is clipping enabled for some element, and it hides a lot of children; but clipping is slower by itself).

Comment: Your rule of thumb is a good one. If it is one unit from the outside perspective then using nesting is the best way forward. That allows you to change the visibility, opacity, etc, but just affecting the "top level" item of that "component"